# How do I make my fingerpicking patterns interesting?

Tags: guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, accompaniment

I'm pretty used to picking through patterns in 3/4, 4/4, 6/8, 8/8 and 12/8 over arbitrary chords, but the novelty of this skill has worn off. How do I create patterns that doesn't get repetetive during a song?

Take this as an example:

How do I get there? The player doesn't just pick over the chords, he mixes it up and makes it interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Start by imitating people whose style you like. Then you can use what you learn when you're making your own music.

I listened to the video you posted and here is what I hear:

1. Basic 2-beat pattern for 7 measures (if in 2/4)
2. Simple fill (one note at a time, 3 or 4 notes in a row) for 1 measure
3. Repeat with a different basic pattern

I heard the following basic patterns used:

Low string eighth note, middle string eighth note, high 2-note chord quarter note
Large chord quarter note, middle string quarter note
Large chord 2 quarter notes in a row

If you want to get obsessive you can always go through the recording and try to imitate it in an exact note-for-note way, or look for a printed tablature, but if you're just looking for fresh ideas you might just try this kind of careful listening to a lot of different songs in styles that you like.

Comment: I would add that most performers will rarely pick the same exact pattern twice in different performances.